# How to access gii using homestead

Tags: yii2, gii

I am using homestead as my dev environment for my yii2 tutorial and my problem is I cannot configure the lines below to access gii in `http://hostname/index.php?r=gii`

```
    'gii' => [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.1', '::1', '192.168.0.*', '192.168.178.20'] 
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Gii working with this config in `conf/web.php`

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
    // configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment

    $config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
    $config['modules']['gii'] = [
        'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
        'allowedIPs' => ['192.168.56.1'],
    ];
}
```

Using Yii 2.0.4

Look for `YII_ENV_DEV` in the `web.php` file

Forgot to mention.  If you're using Vagrant, I can share my `bootstrap.sh` file which creates a Yii2 enviroment from Ubuntu Precise.  Not homestead needed at all.  Just drop me a note if you need it.

Comment: hey! thanks! I already found the answer. 

'allowedIPs' => ['192.168.10.*'],

because my ip in my .yaml file is 192.168.10.10